Counter value not displayed in \foreach loop
I try to write a command that displays a table with the number of lines passed as parameter. It's working fine except that in this MWE, the value of the \i variable is not displayed.
I have no idea why... Does someone knows a solution?
Thanks in advance for your answer.
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,svgnames]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={18cm,25cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\makeatletter
\let\@history\@empty
\NewDocumentCommand \historyentry {m} {%
  \g@addto@macro\@history{#1 & & & \\}
}
\NewDocumentCommand \history {} {%
  \begin{tblr}[expand=\@history]{width=\linewidth,colspec={*{4}{X[c,1]}},hlines,vlines}
    Exo & \faSmile[regular] & \faMeh[regular] & \faFrownOpen[regular] \\ 
    \@history{}
  \end{tblr}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\TableauEvaluation}{m}{
  \let\@history\@empty
  \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{
    \historyentry{\i}
  }
  \history
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\TableauEvaluation{3}
\bigskip

\TableauEvaluation{7}
\end{document}



you can try
\expandafter\historyentry\expandafter{\i}

expand \i,
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,svgnames]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={18cm,25cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\makeatletter
\let\@history\@empty
\NewDocumentCommand \historyentry {m} {%
  \g@addto@macro\@history{#1 & & & \\}
}
\NewDocumentCommand \history {} {%
  \begin{tblr}[expand=\@history]{width=\linewidth,colspec={*{4}{X[c,1]}},hlines,vlines}
    Exo & \faSmile[regular] & \faMeh[regular] & \faFrownOpen[regular] \\ 
    \@history
  \end{tblr}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\TableauEvaluation}{m}{
  \let\@history\@empty
  \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{
    \expandafter\historyentry\expandafter{\i}
  }
  \history
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\TableauEvaluation{3}
\bigskip

\TableauEvaluation{7}
\end{document}



Don't use \foreach for such jobs, because it executes every cycle in a group, which is the reason why you always get 1.
I propose a fairly general method. The first column is set at natural width for better appearance.
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[total={18cm,25cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\BuildTableau}{O{\linewidth}mm}
 {% #1 = desired width (default \linewidth)
  % #2 = number of indexed rows
  % #3 = column template (see examples)
  \sylcha_tableau_build:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__sylcha_tableau_body_tl
\seq_new:N \l__sylcha_tableau_header_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \sylcha_tableau_build:nnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__sylcha_tableau_header_seq {} {#3}
  % add the header
  \tl_set:Ne \l__sylcha_tableau_body_tl
   {
    \seq_use:Nn \l__sylcha_tableau_header_seq { & } \exp_not:N \\
   }
  % add the rows (index in the first column and empty cells)
  \int_step_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Ne \l__sylcha_tableau_body_tl
     {
      ##1
      \prg_replicate:nn { \seq_count:N \l__sylcha_tableau_header_seq - 1 } { & }
      \exp_not:N \\
     }
   }
  % print the table
  \noindent
  \begin{tblr}[expand=\l__sylcha_tableau_body_tl]
   {
    width=#1,
    colspec={ c *{\seq_count:N \l__sylcha_tableau_header_seq - 1 }{X[c,1]}},
    hlines,
    vlines,
   }
   \l__sylcha_tableau_body_tl
  \end{tblr}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\BuildTableau{3}{
  {Exo}
  {\faSmile[regular]}
  {\faMeh[regular]}
  {\faFrownOpen[regular]}
}

\bigskip

\BuildTableau[0.5\linewidth]{7}{{Exo}{Good}{Bad}{Ugly}{total}}

\end{document}



With the command \historyentry in the original posting \g@addto@macro is in use. \g@addto@macro does not trigger expansion of tokens. Thus \foreach's grouping in the course of processing \TableauEvaluation is not the only reason for always getting 1.The main reason for always getting 1 is not having expanded the \foreach-"variable" \i in the course of providing the tokens that form \historyentry's argument.
